# redux-thunk and redux-saga simultaneously

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I've come across two sources where it explains how to use two middleware systems together.

The first one says:

> You can add the saga middleware right alongside the thunk middleware. Remember, the order you list middleware does matter.

Code:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, sagaMiddleware))
```

The second one provides this part of code [source2](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-redux-thunks-with-redux-sagas-4aa306854925):

```
 createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, thunk)
```

Is it ok? Or the first one just remind us that the order matters but in case of the order between `saga` and `thunk` it doesn't matter? Maybe there's other reasons to warn about order relatively `saga` and `thunk`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can absolutely use both middleware together.

The ordering matters because the middleware pipeline order is based on the order of arguments to `applyMiddleware()`.  That said, it's primarily a concern when you have a custom middleware that calls `next(action)`, which forwards the action to the next middleware in the pipeline.  With thunks and sagas you're normally calling `dispatch(action)`, which always starts at the beginning of the pipeline.

For more details, see [the Redux FAQ entry on "what is the difference between `next` and `dispatch` in a middleware?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/storesetup#is-it-ok-to-have-more-than-one-middleware-chain-in-my-store-enhancer-what-is-the-difference-between-next-and-dispatch-in-a-middleware-function).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `putResolve` from saga api

```
putResolve(action)
Just like put but the effect is blocking (if promise is returned from dispatch it will wait for its resolution) and will bubble up errors from downstream.
```

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/
Since redux-thunks return a promise, you can call them directly in your sagas and wait for a return value.
Also, it will bubble up any errors.